# WindowsRuntimeComponent runtime error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am having problems creating a managed class with namespace in visual studio 2012 Windows Runtime Component of C++.

Below is the code:-

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1
{
     public ref class Class1 sealed
     {
           public:
               Class1();
               string getString(string desc);
      };
}
```

i'm getting error at 'public' which it expected a declaration.
beside that, exception return by visual studio 2012 is error C2059:syntax error:'public', error C2143:syntax error:missing ';' before '{', error C2447:'{':missing function header (old-style-formal list?)

Can anyone help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: It is not a runtime error.  You'll get this kind of *compile* error when the compiler isn't configured properly, not compiling with the /ZW option to enable the C++/CX language extension.  Be sure to get started with the correct project template.  Project + Properties, General, "Windows Store App Support" needs to be Yes.

Answer (score 1):

oYou have to change the runtime compiler. Go to Project -> Properties -> General and change it to "Common Language Runtime Support to /clr".

EDIT: Well, there is no need to worry about all the compiler errors. Google is your friend! if you don't know how to fix it, just look for it. All errors are described in detail. But most of the errors are self-explanatory, e.g. "error C4703, potentially uninitialized local pointer variable used" says you have to initialize your var `int *xxx=0;`.

Comment: sorry. can you explain more detail. because I can't find "Common Language Runtime"

Comment: I found that already. But I get a new error which is error D8016:'/ZI' and '/clr' command-line options are incompatible. Can any one help me?

Comment: In the project properties go to C/C++ -> General and change Debug information Format to "Program Database /Zi"

Comment: After change Debug information Format to "Program Database /Zi", I get more errors. As an example error C1003:error count exceeds 100;stoping compilation, error C2054:expected '(' to follow 'using', error C2059:syntax error:';'.

Comment: the piece of code you posted I can compile. Which classes do you also have?

Comment: getString method is a function use to select data from database and it is just connect with other sqlite source code only. So, when i compile i get so many errors.

Comment: Now I'm getting an error which is error D8016:'/clr' and '/EHs' command-line options are incompatible. I don't know how to solve it can anyone teach me?

Comment: What kind of project did you create? ;) In C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Enable C++ Exceptions change to /EHa. Or create a new Win32 Console Appliction where all these compiler options are by default (except /clr)

Comment: windows 8 application using javascript call native code creating by using visual studio c++. The error is fixed. But now getting a new error which is error D8016:'/clr' and '/RTC1' command-line options are incompatible.

Comment: In the same window change Basic Runtime Checks to Default. This kind of errors says you have wrong options. So google for e.g. "c++ /rtc1" and will find the proper option within properties so you can play with it

Comment: Thank you. But I think the error is unlimited. After solve the error it will come with a new error such as now i get an error said that error C4703:potentially uninitialized local pointer variable 'xxx' used. And i don't know how to fix it.